# Codeception. How can I use more then one url in my acceptance test?

Tags: php, automated-tests, codeception

Sorry for my bad english.
I'm only starting to use codeception. There is need to use two urls in one acceptance test (website (url: example.com) and administrator interface(url: edit-example.com)). But I don't know how to realize this.
I tried to do something like this:

acceptance.suite.yml

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: example.com
```

testCept.php

```
$website = example.com
$adm_int = edit-example.com

$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
// Go to website and do some actions
$I->amOnPage($website);
// some code

// Then go to administrator interface and do some actions
$I->amOnPage($adm_int);
//some code

// Then I go again to website and look that changes confirmed
$I->amOnPage($website);
// some code
```

But in this case url of website concatenates with url, specified in config file acceptance.suite.yml. And test goes to url  example.com/example.com and in case with administrator interface it goes to example.com/edit-example.com.

The problem is in url, that specified in config file acceptance.suite.yml. If I delete url from this config file - codeception returns exception:

```
[Codeception\Exception\ModuleConfigException]                     
  WebDriver module is not configured!                               

  Options: browser, url are required                                
  Please, update the configuration and set all the required fields  



Exception trace:
 () at PhpstormProjects\MyProject\general\data\lib\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Module.php:89
 Codeception\Module->validateConfig() at PhpstormProjects\MyProject\general\data\lib\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Module.php:65
 Codeception\Module->_setConfig() at PhpstormProjects\MyProject\general\data\lib\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Module.php:58
 Codeception\Module->__construct() at n/a:n/a
 ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs() at PhpstormProjects\MyProject\general\data\lib\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Lib\Di.php:75
 Codeception\Lib\Di->instantiate() at PhpstormProjects\MyProject\general\data\lib\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Lib\ModuleContainer.php:109
 Codeception\Lib\ModuleContainer->instantiate() at PhpstormProjects\MyProject\general\data\lib\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Lib\ModuleContainer.php:62
 Codeception\Lib\ModuleContainer->create() at PhpstormProjects\MyProject\general\data\lib\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\SuiteManager.php:71
 Codeception\SuiteManager->__construct() at PhpstormProjects\MyProject\general\data\lib\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Codecept.php:200
 Codeception\Codecept->runSuite() at PhpstormProjects\MyProject\general\data\lib\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Codecept.php:172
 Codeception\Codecept->run() at PhpstormProjects\MyProject\general\data\lib\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Command\Run.php:184
 Codeception\Command\Run->execute() at PhpstormProjects\MyProject\general\data\lib\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:257
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at PhpstormProjects\MyProject\general\data\lib\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:874
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at PhpstormProjects\MyProject\general\data\lib\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at PhpstormProjects\MyProject\general\data\lib\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at PhpstormProjects\MyProject\general\data\lib\vendor\codeception\codeception\codecept:28
```

May be there are some instruments in codeception that allow to use absolute urls in function amOnPage()?

Did somebody solve this problem? May be someone have an idea how to help with that problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use full url with protocol:

```
$website = 'http://example.com';
$adm_int = 'http://edit-example.com';
```

And use [amOnUrl](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#amOnUrl) method instead of amOnPage

Comment: It doesn't applies to my problem. It will be the same. Test will go to http://example.com/http://example.com. My problem is concatenation url from config acceptance.suite.yml and url from test file.

Comment: I am sure that it does.

Comment: Use amOnUrl method instead of amOnPage

Answer (score 3):

Open web page at the given absolute URL and sets its hostname as the base host.

```
<?php
 $I->amOnUrl('http://codeception.com');
 $I->amOnPage('/quickstart'); // moves to http://codeception.com/quickstart
?>
```

and also start the selenium server for run the Automation in the Browsers like Chrome, firefox and all

for setup and start the selenium server use the below command in the Command Prompt

```
  cmd:   webdriver-manager update 
  cmd:   webdriver-manager start
```

Please go through the below code and add browser name in the acceptance.suite.yml

```
modules:
    enabled:
    - WebDriver
config:
    WebDriver:
        url: 'example.com'
        browser: chrome
```